# Долго выполняется рекурсивный запрос в postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, big-data, apache-spark

Зравствуйте, можно ли как то повысить перформанс текущего запроса? Возможно его надо разбить на несколько запросов с использованием темп таблиц.

У меня есть таблица с иерархией objectid, parentid со 150тыс-5миллионов записей и выполнение текущего запроса подвисает процесс,

```
WITH RECURSIVE data_selection AS (
     select distinct(objectid), parentid, objectid root_id 
     from table_all t1
     where parentid not in (select objectid from table_all)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT distinct(t2.objectid), t2.parentid, ds.root_id
     FROM data_selection ds
     JOIN table_all t2 ON ds.objectid = t2.parentid), 
rootId_grouping AS (
     SELECT '[' || ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(distinct(ds.objectid)), ',') || ']' as objectid, t1.parentid
     FROM data_selection ds
     left join table_all t1 on t1.objectid = root_id
     GROUP BY ds.root_id , t1.parentid)
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(objectid), ',') as objectid, parentid 
FROM rootId_grouping group by parentid;
```

анализ выполнения запроса на 150тыс строк

```
HashAggregate  (cost=293221048.40..293221051.40 rows=200 width=64) (actual time=448991.672..448992.575 rows=1081 loops=1)
  Group Key: rootid_grouping.parentid
  CTE data_selection
    ->  Recursive Union  (cost=1000.44..174119782.29 rows=23923944 width=111) (actual time=531.542..447737.443 rows=9352 loops=1)
          ->  Unique  (cost=1000.44..162028220.39 rows=11944 width=111) (actual time=531.540..446951.751 rows=1134 loops=1)
                ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.44..162027921.50 rows=59778 width=111) (actual time=531.538..446928.089 rows=25727 loops=1)
                      Workers Planned: 2
                      Workers Launched: 2
                      ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using table_all_objectid_idx on table_all t1  (cost=0.42..162020021.61 rows=24908 width=74) (actual time=358.601..366268.250 rows=8576 loops=3)
                            Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 31276
                            Heap Fetches: 0
                            SubPlan 1
                              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..6205.34 rows=119556 width=37) (actual time=0.003..6.446 rows=32894 loops=119556)
                                    ->  Seq Scan on table_all  (cost=0.00..4672.56 rows=119556 width=37) (actual time=0.001..4.784 rows=32504 loops=94212)
          ->  Unique  (cost=1116459.78..1161308.30 rows=2391200 width=106) (actual time=234.343..260.931 rows=2739 loops=3)
                ->  Sort  (cost=1116459.78..1127671.91 rows=4484852 width=106) (actual time=233.456..254.409 rows=31276 loops=3)
                      Sort Key: t2.objectid, t2.parentid, ds.root_id
                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=7685.01..99767.23 rows=4484852 width=106) (actual time=64.580..92.219 rows=31276 loops=3)
                            Hash Cond: ((ds.objectid)::text = (t2.parentid)::text)
                            ->  WorkTable Scan on data_selection ds  (cost=0.00..2388.80 rows=119440 width=64) (actual time=0.003..0.384 rows=3117 loops=3)
                            ->  Hash  (cost=4672.56..4672.56 rows=119556 width=74) (actual time=48.782..48.783 rows=119556 loops=3)
                                  Buckets: 65536  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 3530kB
                                  ->  Seq Scan on table_all t2  (cost=0.00..4672.56 rows=119556 width=74) (actual time=0.020..16.018 rows=119556 loops=3)
  CTE rootid_grouping
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=116005645.66..119085346.11 rows=636800 width=101) (actual time=448604.934..448988.259 rows=1134 loops=1)
          Group Key: ds_1.root_id, t1_1.parentid
          ->  Sort  (cost=116005645.66..116772386.77 rows=306696445 width=101) (actual time=448604.696..448759.035 rows=218440 loops=1)
                Sort Key: ds_1.root_id, t1_1.parentid
                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 25864kB
                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=7685.01..5683504.56 rows=306696445 width=101) (actual time=1139.896..447918.120 rows=218440 loops=1)
                      Hash Cond: ((ds_1.root_id)::text = (t1_1.objectid)::text)
                      ->  CTE Scan on data_selection ds_1  (cost=0.00..478478.88 rows=23923944 width=64) (actual time=531.543..447742.091 rows=9352 loops=1)
                      ->  Hash  (cost=4672.56..4672.56 rows=119556 width=74) (actual time=57.091..57.092 rows=119556 loops=1)
                            Buckets: 65536  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 3644kB
                            ->  Seq Scan on table_all t1_1  (cost=0.00..4672.56 rows=119556 width=74) (actual time=0.026..18.613 rows=119556 loops=1)
  ->  CTE Scan on rootid_grouping  (cost=0.00..12736.00 rows=636800 width=64) (actual time=448604.940..448989.470 rows=1134 loops=1)
Planning time: 2.741 ms
Execution time: 449001.698 ms
```

Пример данных таблицы table_all, индексы на objectid и parentid созданы

| objectid | parentid | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5d1eb711-a2fd-4ca5-beab-c8cddb37f2c8 | 3b82621b-6541-4c57-a0ff-42e0011afa95 | value |
| 039635e8-1831-4027-83bf-cdafb7cabe9f | 5d1eb711-a2fd-4ca5-beab-c8cddb37f2c8 | value |
| 55c7ef23-6a69-48f2-be80-6552ddf9e1f5 | 5d1eb711-a2fd-4ca5-beab-c8cddb37f2c8 | value |
| b0e39676-73a4-45fd-a179-7140722cc9f8 | 55c7ef23-6a69-48f2-be80-6552ddf9e1f5 | value |

результат

| objectid | parentid |
| --- | --- |
| [5d1eb711-a2fd-4ca5-beab-c8cddb37f2c8,039635e8-1831-4027-83bf-cdafb7cabe9f,55c7ef23-6a69-48f2-be80-6552ddf9e1f5,b0e39676-73a4-45fd-a179-7140722cc9f8] | 3b82621b-6541-4c57-a0ff-42e0011afa95 |

Возможно стоит воспользоваться дополнительным фреймворком.
Пробовал spark, к сожалению не умеет он работать с рекурсивными запросами на сколько я знаю.

Comment: Ваши индексы, скорее всего, не работают. Этому несколько причин. Явная, из 4-х запросов к table_all вы 3 раза полоностью ее выбираете. Вторая(могу ошибаться в части postgree), конструкция not in не будет использовать индексы. Итого, вы получаете как минимум 4 полных чтения таблиц

Comment: Там не 4 полных чтения таблицы. `actual time=0.001..4.784 rows=32504 loops=94212)` означает, что было 94 тыс. чтения и время каждого до 4 мс. , т.е. 94212*4 ~ 376 секунд. Попробуйте заменить `parentid not in (select objectid from table_all)` на `not exists (select 1 from table_all tt where tt.objectid = t1.parentid)`

Comment: Ещё странное сочетание `distinct` и `union all`. Если убрать `distinct` и заменить на `union`, то получится ровно тот же самый результат, при этом Постгрису будет легче понять, что требуется. И, кстати, а дубликаты там вообще возможны? Может ты зря Постгрис напрягаешь дедупликацией? ИД выглядят как UUID, а хранятся как? Если как строки, то это минимум 36 байт хранить/читать/размещать в памяти/сравнивать, тогда как если хранить в формате UUID, то будет 16 байт.

Comment: спасибо за ответы, с exists отработало за 4сек. distinct необходим, и к сожалению objectid это строка, буду что то с этим думать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основное время в запросе тратится на этот подзапрос:

```
select distinct(objectid), parentid, objectid root_id 
from table_all t1
where parentid not in (select objectid from table_all)
```

`(actual time=0.001..4.784 rows=32504 loops=94212)` означает, что было 94212 тыс. выполений сканирования таблицы и время каждого до 4.7 мс., таким образом сумарное время этой ветки 94212*4 ~ 376 секунд.

Тут видно, что индексы не используются.

Обычно `not in` плохо работает и замена на `not exits` позволяет postgres задействовать индекс.

Т.е. в вашем запросе нужно заменить `parentid not in (select objectid from table_all)` на `not exists (select 1 from table_all tt where tt.objectid = t1.parentid)`.